# Expect Script: How to provide default values if arguments are not passed

Tags: expect

I have a simple expect script which does accept two input arguments viz. username and password. In my case, if script is called without any arguments, I want to assign some default value to command line arguments. How can it be done?

Answer (score 7):

```
set argv [lassign $argv username password]
if {$username eq ""} {set username default_user}
if {$password eq ""} {set password default_password}
```

Comment: the `set argv ...` part overrides `argv` needlessly. just have this line read as `lassign $argv username password` and that's it